# Custom template file to use themes html/page.tpl

Tags: theming

I have a custom module (using Drupal 7) that adds a page using `hook_menu()`. Its callback just prints the value returned from `theme('mytheme_hook')`.

If the content of my template file is simply `'hello world'` I get only a white screen with the text output.

Is it possible for this page to extend the theme's `html.tpl` (and even `page.tpl`) with `'hello world'` inserted in the 'content section' of the page?

[This](https://www.drupal.org/node/347008) looks like a similar thing I am trying to achieve, but it doesn't offer a solution.

Comment: Not sure why @kiamlaluna insists this is a duplicate when it's not. I will provide my edit here so it won't be rolled back... **I wanted to extend my themes template files**... i **did not** want to display bare html from my hook menu callback... that is what was happening as an unwanted side effect of my attempt.

Comment: The solution for those who come here is to make sure you `return` `theme('theme_hook')` from your menu callback for it to use themes html/page.tpl. if you just print it will display what you print without using themes `html.tpl.php` or `page.tpl.php`

Answer (score 0):

If you want your content to be inserted in the content section of the page you just need to return it (as HTML, or render array) from your page callback function. Then you can override the template of any (html/page/node) level for this page by standard [theme hook suggestion](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) and customize it.